# How to read specific text from a embed message on Discord (webhook)

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, embed, discord

When a webhook is sent to Discord I want the Link/URL contained within the embedded message to open.

So far I have tried to read the embed and split it in to a list. Then look for the item that starts with https and use that item.

Having no luck with the split though.
When I use split it gives me [ 'Object Object' ] when I try and display it.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.username.toString() === 'Persons Nam Here') {
    for(var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
      var hookcontent = message.embeds[i].toString().split(",")
      console.log(hookcontent);
```

It should give me a list of the webhook contents all split into seperate items by ","

Then I will look for an item that contains "https:" and that will be the item.

Comment: What do you see when you do `console.log(message.embeds[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

By calling `toString` on the embed, you are simply getting the object as a string. Unless the lib provides a toString override that resolves the properties of the embed (which it doesn't). What you need to do is actually refer to those properties yourself.

For example, `embeds[0].description` would give you whatever is in the embed's description. 
Alternatively you can make your own function that reads every property and return a single string containing the concatenated embed properties.